# How to remove subdirectories using mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

All my site url reads

http://example.com/myfolder/main/other/extra/index.php

I want it to rewritten as

http://example.com/index.php

Comment: is your server apache ? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the below rule :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^myfolder/main/other/extra/index.php(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php$1 [r=301,nc]
```